# ./bashrc permission denied on windows10

Tags: bash, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a ubuntu on windows10, and I have added some alias to ./bashrc

But then when I reopened ubuntu the colors of the text are all gone with `-bash: /home/chikuma/.bashrc: Permission denied` shown at the first line.
Typing `bash` also got denied.

I deleted all the stuff I've added in `./bashrc` but it didn't make any changes.

What is happening ??

Comment: Do you have permission to read `.bashrc`?

Comment: Did you edit `.bashrc` file using a Windows-based GUI editor? File permissions should be `-rw-r--r--` (the 1st column in the output from `ls -alF ./.bashrc`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 10 does not know about file permissions in Ubuntu subsystem.
If you want to edit .bashrc just use native Ubuntu nano or vim code editors.

To open .bashrc use:

```
sudo nano .bashrc
```

To set file permissions:

```
chmod 644 .bashrc
```

This permissions is equal to

> rw-r--r--

Comment: Why would you recommend using `sudo nano .bashrc` rather than `nano .bashrc`? Never use `sudo` unless you have a specific need for root access.

Comment: Yes, you right. In case above Windows 10 will delete all permissions in .bashrc. And you can't open the file without  `sudo` to edit. After `chmod` command `nano .bashrc` will work fine.